# jquery deferred in loop for sequential processing

Tags: jquery

The goal: loop through an array of urls ONE AT A TIME, letting them load completely using postMessage to determine when finished (some of the pages will take a long time)

Implemented this, but it's not working quite right: [jquery deferred in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552302/jquery-deferred-in-for-loop)

Implemented this, and it's working, but not in a loop because the javascript only opens the last window: http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

```
function scrape(url){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
      var myPopUp = window.open(url,'myWindow');
      setInterval(function(){
        var message = 'Hello!  The time is: ' + (new Date().getTime());
        console.log('Scraper Launcher:  sending message:  ' + message);
        myPopUp.postMessage(message,domain);//send the message and target URI
        },6000);

        //listen to holla back
        window.addEventListener('message',function(event) {
                if(event.origin !== domain) return;
                console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
                if(event.data == 'You were successful!'){
                   console.log('closing child window');
                   myPopUp.close();
                   deferred.resolve('Success');
                }else{
                   console.log('oh dear, FAILURE: ' + urls[i]);
                   deferred.resolve('Failure');
                }
             },false);


    return deferred.promise();
}

    var urls = [domain +"/url1",domain +"/url2"];

   $("#launch_windows").click(function(){
      console.log('launching');
      for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
         (function(i){
            console.log('NOW i is ' + i + ' and url is ' + urls[i]);
            $.when(scrape(urls[i])).then(function(results){
               console.log('DONE (' + results + ')with ' + urls[i]);
            });
          })(i);
      }
    });
```

And if this is totally horrible logic and code, I'm all ears for suggestions.

Answer (score 9):

I like to solve these problems (sequential loops of async operations) by creating a resolved $.Deferred, adding to the chain, and assigning the value of that deferred to the new promise with each iteration.

```
$("#launch_windows").click(function(){
    console.log("launching");
    var dfd = $.Deferred().resolve();
    for(i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
        (function(i){
            dfd = dfd.then(function(){
                return scrape(urls[i]);
            }).then(function(results){
                console.log("results: "+results);
            });
        })(i);
    }
});
```

Cleaner version with a forEach instead of IIFE to provide closure:

```
var dfd = $.Deferred().resolve();
urls.forEach(function(url){
    dfd = dfd.then(function(){
        return scrape(url);
    }).then(function(results){
        console.log("results: "+results);
    });
});
```

Your problem lied in the `$.when` within each iteration. On the first iteration `$.when` created a new promise (unnecessary btw since scrape returns a promise), and then added a `then` to process results. On the next iteration, this original promise is not referenced and a new one is created for the next url (before the first scrape was completed!) and so on.

This solution keeps all of your async operations in the same $.Deferred chain, executing them sequentially (what you want).

You do get points for using the IIFE to freeze the value of i though!

Heres a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpo4uoou/1/)